# Implementing jsp:include at Java

Tags: java, file, recursion, pattern-matching

I want to start from a given file(i.e. a.html) and if I see a pattern as like that:

```
<!--$include file="b.html"-->
```

I will go that file(b.html) and take whatever it has and all files will be written as into a final file(i.e. output.html)

If I see an include at b.html I should follow that include too and take whatever it has and I should repeat it recursively at Java?

Any ideas?

**PS:** It is similar to what jsp:include does but I want to implement it myself. I will implement it as a Maven plugin and I constructed a maven plugin for my need however using recursion or not and using a regex pattern or any other efficient way is what I am looking for.

Comment: Any ideas ? Sounds great! Do you have a question other than that ?

Comment: Try looking up the `include` directive for jsp?  Sounds like exactly what you're looking for... (or the same from asp, or php...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to create a function to get files list, e.g. `getFileList(htmlFile:File): File[]`;
2. Create a `readline` function and create a function to parse line which pattern is like `"^.*<!\\-\\-\\$include file\\=\"(.+)\\.(html|htm)\" \\-\\->.*$"`, this is a regular expression, it can match what your searched regex. let's defined the function's name as `checkRule(line:String):boolean`
3. If `checkRule` return true, and get file name, then recursively invoke `getFileList` by passing just found file name.
4. Be careful about infinite loop. For example, `a.html` includes `b.html`, and `b.html` includes `a.html`, it would become infinite loop. So you need to check file list to ignore the file.

Good luck!!!